# como fazer um select em php para um campo de busca por datas

Tags: php

Estou com um problema para fazer um Select, preciso de ajuda, estou programando em php, para fazer buscas em um banco de dados preciso fazer um campo de busca por datas. 
Já consegui fazer o campo de busca por data especifica, mas preciso fazer a busca com intervalo entre as datas. (exemplo: busca de 20/05/2020 a 31/05/2020).

o select que fiz para procurar por uma data foi esse:
case 'pesquisareduroamdata':

```
        global $linhadataa; 
        global $rsdataa; 

        $dataa = new dataa();

        $data = $_POST['data'];


        $dataa->pesquisareduroamdata("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE data LIKE '%$data%' && ssid = 'EDUROAM' ");
        $linhadataa = $dataa->Linha;
        $rsdataa = $dataa->Result;
```

se alguém souber me ajude.

Comment: Em seu banco de dados o campo `data` é do tipo string?

Answer (score 2):

Considerando o seu exemplo, há muitos problemas no seu código além da consulta. Mas focando na sua pergunta e considerando que a coluna `data` citada é do tipo DATE,
há duas maneiras simples de fazer isso. A primeira é utilizando, no caso do MySql, a cláusula `BETWEEN`, desse modo:

```sql
"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE data `BETWEEN` '$data1' AND '$data2' "
```

E o segundo modo é comparando valores:

```sql
"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE data >= '$data1' AND data <= '$data2' "
```

Em caso de a coluna `data` ser to tipo texto, embora não seja o recomendado, ainda assim dá pra realizar a consulta utilizando a função `STR_TO_DATE`. Detalhes [nesse link](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/)